# Update statement from another table with multiple criteria

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE PHYS_COUNT_TAG
SET COUNT_QTY = (
        SELECT qty
        FROM MC_PART_LOCATION
        WHERE MC_PART_LOCATION.part_id = PHYS_COUNT_TAG.PART_ID
            AND MC_PART_LOCATION.location_id = PHYS_COUNT_TAG.LOCATION_ID
    )
```

The above code does not work. On execution I get the error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "PCT.PART_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "PCT.LOCATION_ID" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Writing in all caps, won't do any good.

Comment: sorry I did NOT mean to write in caps I work in caps on my work computer because of requirements it was an accident :)  thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this one (`T-SQL`) -

```
UPDATE p
SET COUNT_QTY = l.qty
FROM PHYS_COUNT_TAG p
JOIN MC_PART_LOCATION l ON l.part_id = p.PART_ID
    AND l.location_id = p.LOCATION_ID
```

Comment: Thank you - it did update 1061 records but can't figure out why it is leaving off about 40?  I did a select with the same basic criteria and there are more?

Comment: #1. Perhaps, because your don't have any index on join columns. #2. Yes, of course.